# Xiaomi gaming laptop 16.04 quick discharge

Tags: 16.04, power-management

I've recently bought Xiaomi gaming laptop and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. After using it for some time I noticed that my laptop dies after 2-3 hours of using. I installed powertop and tlp so almost every thing in powertop's tunables tab is "good". Yet the discharge rate is still pretty high (14-17 watts while simply browsing or idle). I have my nvidia driver installed but have intel "GPU" selected in order to save power.
Laptop specs: GeForce 1060, i7-8750
Powertop output:

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 16.6 W
The estimated remaining time is 2 hours, 56 minutes
Summary: 1304,5 wakeups/second,  0,0 GPU ops/seconds, 0,0 VFS ops/sec and 23,3% CPU use
Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  21.5 W      0,0 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: enp7s0 (r8169)
  2.73 W    100,0%                      Device         USB device: ITE Device(8910) (ITE Tech. Inc.)
 45.1 mW     75,6 ms/s     236,3        Process        /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=11984423123929607261,6370143250280949661,131072 --service-pipe-t
 37.3 mW     35,7 ms/s     337,4        Process        /opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

It's clear that somehow enp7s0 consumes 21w which is something that I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

[Check this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175900/battery-drain-processor-always-at-max/1176373#1176373)
Had a similar issue and found out a bug in the touchpad interruptions. The script in the solution solved the problem for me.