# Battery drain & processor always at max

Tags: 18.04, power-management, intel, cpu, io

So, I've installed Ubuntu on my new gaming laptop (Xiaomi Gaming Laptop 2, NVidia GTX 1060, I7 8750H, 16GB RAM) and I've realised a very fast battery drain and heating, even at idle. At the beginning it was around 35W (as shown by `powertop`), then I learned to force the Intel graphics card instead of the NVidia one and managed to turn it down to 20-25 W. Also installed `tlp` and `cpupower` and set it to `powersave`.

The issue seems to be (as shown by `lscpu`) that the processor is always too high (haven seen it under 2.5 GHz and most of the time 4 GHz). Any idea why this could be? `top` doesn't show any process consuming more than 7% of the CPU at idling. Is there any known issue related to `intel_pstate`?

EDIT: seems like I found one possible cause for this. Checking `top` again shows that an IRQ process related to `intel-gpio` is constantly making use of around 15-20% of the CPU. Any ideas? How can I trace which component is causing this?

Comment: Are you using the Nvidia or the i7 graphic card when it drains out?

Comment: @dadexix86 it drains with both. Before deactivating the Nvidia graphic card it was around 30-35 W, and with the Intel one it keeps between 20-22 W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the cause, I'll post it in case anyone has the same issue.
I googled the exact device that showed in the IRQ, and found that some MSI PS63 users who installed Linux found themselves with the same issue:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1862570#p1862570

The problem comes from the touchpad. In my case, rebinding the i2c bus solved the problem:

```
sudo -i
echo -n "i2c_designware.0" > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/i2c_designware/unbind 
echo -n "i2c_designware.0" > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/i2c_designware/bind
```

Comment: Does that persists between reboots? Is this a thorough solution or just a hack to make it work again for some time?

Comment: @vanadium this fixes it until the next reboot, but you can set it up to be run at startup and it pretty much solves it permanently.